# Grid View Update not working for title field

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, gridview

i have created a   gridview to update the news table in my database which will  then  dynamically  update my news page but   i am having problems updating the title field all other fields seem to  be updating fine (time,author and content) but the title field doesnt  seem to record the update.

**here is the code for  the grid view on my news_overiew pasge where you can update the  news items:**

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/MasterPageCMS.master" %>

<script runat="server">

</script>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" Runat="Server">
    <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataSourceID="news" Height="252px" OnSelectedIndexChanged="GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged" Width="746px">
        <Columns>
            <asp:CommandField ShowDeleteButton="True" ShowEditButton="True" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="title" HeaderText="title" SortExpression="title" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="date" HeaderText="date" SortExpression="date" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="author" HeaderText="author" SortExpression="author" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="content" HeaderText="content" SortExpression="content" />
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="news" runat="server" ConflictDetection="CompareAllValues" 
        OldValuesParameterFormatString="original_{0}" 
        ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:nas connection %>" 
        DeleteCommand="DELETE FROM [news] 
                         WHERE [title] = @original_title 
                           AND [date] = @original_date 
                           AND [author] = @original_author 
                           AND [content] = @original_content" 
        InsertCommand="INSERT INTO [news] ([title], [date], [author], [content]) 
                         VALUES (@title, @date, @author, @content)" 
        SelectCommand="SELECT [title], [date], [author], [content] FROM [news]" 
        UpdateCommand="UPDATE [news] SET [date] = @date, [author] = @author, 
                              [content] = @content 
                         WHERE [title] = @original_title 
                           AND [date] = @original_date 
                           AND [author] = @original_author 
                           AND [content] = @original_content">
        <DeleteParameters>
            <asp:Parameter Name="original_title" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="original_date" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="original_author" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="original_content" Type="String" />
        </DeleteParameters>
        <InsertParameters>
            <asp:Parameter Name="title" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="date" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="author" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="content" Type="String" />
        </InsertParameters>
        <UpdateParameters>
            <asp:Parameter Name="date" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="author" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="content" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="original_title" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="original_date" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="original_author" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="original_content" Type="String" />
        </UpdateParameters>
    </asp:SqlDataSource>
    <br />
    <br />
</asp:Content>
```

Comment: The `title` field seems to be missing from the update query. By the way, did you consider using a primary key (a unique ID) to identify your records? It would be more reliable than matching the content of all the fields.

Comment: [title] = original_title AND [date] = original_date AND [author] = original_author AND [content] = original_content"> is that not the update title query?

Comment: You have: `UPDATE [news] SET [date] = @date, [author] = @author, ...`. The `title` is not among the `SET` fields; it is only in the `WHERE` clause. You should add it to the `SET` part, and also to the list of `UpdateParameters`.